# Encoding conversion in java

Tags: java, character-encoding, converters

Is there any free java library which I can use to convert string in one encoding to other encoding, something like [`iconv`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)? I'm using Java version 1.3.

Comment: Related: [*Save cyrillic while change String encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1251 in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75293780/642706)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't need a library beyond the standard one - just use [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). (You can just use the String constructors and getBytes methods, but personally I don't like just working with the names of character encodings. Too much room for typos.)

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, you can still use Charset instances but have the ease of use of the String methods: [new String(bytes, charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%2C%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) and [String.getBytes(charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29).

See "[URL Encoding (or: 'What are those "`%20`" codes in URLs?')](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)".

Comment: I prefer new String(byte[], encoding) and String.getBytes(encoding) in most cases, because they are simple one-liners as opposed to the more powerful but more complicated API of Charset (which, BTW, is only available in Java 1.4+).

Comment: Yes, it's a shame that the Charset API is so complicated. The .NET System.Encoding class does this really well, IMO - and keeps the functionality out of String.

Comment: Links fixed. See http://www.free-scripts.net/html_tutorial/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 22):

[`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) should be what you are looking for, no ?

Many network protocols and files store their characters with a byte-oriented character set such as `ISO-8859-1` (`ISO-Latin-1`).
However, Java's native character encoding is [<del>Unicode</del>](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) UTF16BE (Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order).

See [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html). That doesn't mean `UTF16` is the default charset (i.e.: the default "mapping between sequences of sixteen-bit **[Unicode code units](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode)** and sequences of bytes"):

> Every instance of the Java virtual machine has a default charset, which may or may not be one of the standard charsets.
> [`US-ASCII`, `ISO-8859-1` a.k.a. `ISO-LATIN-1`, `UTF-8`, `UTF-16BE`, `UTF-16LE`, `UTF-16`]
> The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying operating system.

This example demonstrates how to convert `ISO-8859-1` encoded bytes in a `ByteBuffer` to a string in a `CharBuffer` and visa versa.

```
// Create the encoder and decoder for ISO-8859-1
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

try {
    // Convert a string to ISO-LATIN-1 bytes in a ByteBuffer
    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("a string"));

    // Convert ISO-LATIN-1 bytes in a ByteBuffer to a character ByteBuffer and then to a string.
    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
    String s = cbuf.toString();
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
}
```

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding! UTF-8, UTF-16 etc. are. See 
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @SealedSun: very true. I have fixed that "java native encoding" section in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would just like to add that if the String is originally encoded using the wrong encoding it might be impossible to change it to another encoding without errors.
The question does not state that the conversion here is made from wrong encoding to correct encoding but I personally stumbled to this question just because of this situation so just a heads up for others as well.

This answer in other question gives an explanation why the conversion does not always yield correct results
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2623793/4702806

Answer (score 0):

It is a whole lot easier if you think of unicode as a character set (which it actually is - it is very basically the numbered set of all known characters). You can encode it as UTF-8 (1-3 bytes per character depending) or maybe UTF-16 (2 bytes per character or 4 bytes using surrogate pairs).

Back in the mist of time Java used to use UCS-2 to encode the unicode character set. This could only handle 2 bytes per character and is now obsolete. It was a fairly obvious hack to add surrogate pairs and move up to UTF-16.

A lot of people think they should have used UTF-8 in the first place. When Java was originally written unicode had far more than 65535 characters anyway...