# How do I convert between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, java-me, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Does anyone know how to convert a string from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 and back in Java?

I'm getting a string from the web and saving it in the RMS (J2ME), but I want to preserve the special chars and get the string from the RMS but with the ISO-8859-1 encoding. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In general, you can't do this. UTF-8 is capable of encoding any Unicode code point. ISO-8859-1 can handle only a tiny fraction of them. So, transcoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 is no problem. Going backwards from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 will cause "replacement characters" (�) to appear in your text when unsupported characters are found.

To transcode text:

```
byte[] latin1 = ...
byte[] utf8 = new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

or

```
byte[] utf8 = ...
byte[] latin1 = new String(utf8, "UTF-8").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

You can exercise more control by using the lower-level [`Charset`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/package-summary.html) APIs. For example, you can raise an exception when an un-encodable character is found, or use a different character for replacement text.

Comment: For more information on character encoding and why it rightfully doesn't make much sense to go from UTF-8 to ISO-8859 (or ASCII or ANSI for that matter), see this explanation: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Here's a good summary from said link: `There are hundreds of traditional encodings which can only store some code points correctly and change all the other code points into question marks. Some popular encodings of English text are Windows-1252 (the Windows 9x standard for Western European languages) and ISO-8859-1, aka Latin-1 (also useful for any Western European language). But try to store Russian or Hebrew letters [or special chars] in these encodings and you get a bunch of question marks. UTF 7, 8, 16, and 32 all have the nice property of being able to store any code point correctly.`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Windows-1252 (Windows Latin 1) extends ISO-8859-1 (official Latin 1) by filling in some of the "Unicode control" characters 0x80 - 0xbf. Even browsers on Mac and Linux respect that. So at some spots use Windows-1252 instead.

Answer (score 21):

***Which worked for me:***
*("üzüm bağları" is the correct written in Turkish)*

Convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8:

```
String encodedWithISO88591 = "Ã¼zÃ¼m baÄlarÄ±";
String decodedToUTF8 = new String(encodedWithISO88591.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
//Result, decodedToUTF8 --> "üzüm bağları"
```

Convert UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

```
String encodedWithUTF8 = "üzüm bağları";
String decodedToISO88591 = new String(encodedWithUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
//Result, decodedToISO88591 --> "Ã¼zÃ¼m baÄlarÄ±"
```

Comment: What would happen if you write the following code: `String a=new String(encodedWithUTF8.getBytes("ISO88591"), "ISO-8859-1")` and `String b=new String(encodedWithUTF8.getBytes("ISO88591"), "UTF-8")`? If the string is in one encoding and we get bytes using the other, what's going on under the hood?

Comment: You can try them and see the results on your IDE, and if you follow this URL http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset) you will see the method definition. I don't know the exact detail of the process.

Comment: If someone needs this - I think the above commands would do the following: `a` would take `UTF-8`'s bytes, convert them into `ISO` bytes and then use a table `bytes->chars` of `ISO` encoding to print the string out. In case of string `b` it would use a table `bytes->chars` of `UTF-8` therefore mapping essencially `ISO` bytes according to `UTF` rules.

`a` will be printed out OK even though it's `ISO`, because Java doesn't mess up it's inner storing of bytes. `b` may be damaged because some of the `ISO`'s chars are going to be printed out as if they belonged to `UTF` encoding.

Comment: Is there any third party tool that can convert all the files in a repository to UTF-8?

Answer (score 7):

Here is an easy way with String output (I created a method to do this):

```
public static String (String input){
    String output = "";
    try {
        /* From ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 */
        output = new String(input.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        /* From UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 */
        output = new String(input.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
// Example
input = "Música";
output = "MÃºsica";
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a `String`, you can do that:

```
String s = "test";
try {
    s.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    uee.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have a 'broken' `String`, you did something wrong, converting a `String` to a `String` in another encoding is defenetely not the way to go! You can convert a `String` to a `byte[]` and vice-versa (given an encoding). In Java `String`s are AFAIK encoded with `UTF-16` but that's an implementation detail.

Say you have a `InputStream`, you can read in a `byte[]` and then convert that to a `String` using

```
byte[] bs = ...;
String s;
try {
    s = new String(bs, encoding);
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    uee.printStackTrace();
}
```

or even better (thanks to erickson) use `InputStreamReader` like that:

```
InputStreamReader isr;
try {
     isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, encoding);
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    uee.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you have an InputStream, you should wrap it with an InputStreamReader.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to convert an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8 string.

```
private static String convertIsoToUTF8(String example) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new String(example.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
}
```

If we want to convert an UTF-8 string to ISO-8859-1 string.

```
private static String convertUTF8ToISO(String example) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new String(example.getBytes("utf-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
}
```

Moreover, a method that converts an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8 string without using the constructor of class String.

```
public static String convertISO_to_UTF8_personal(String strISO_8859_1) {
    String res = "";
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strISO_8859_1.length() - 1; i++) {
        char ch = strISO_8859_1.charAt(i);
        char chNext = strISO_8859_1.charAt(i + 1);
        if (ch <= 127) {
            res += ch;
        } else if (ch == 194 && chNext >= 128 && chNext <= 191) {
            res += chNext;
        } else if(ch == 195 && chNext >= 128 && chNext <= 191){
            int resNum = chNext + 64;
            res += (char) resNum;
        } else if(ch == 194){
            res += (char) 173;
        } else if(ch == 195){
            res += (char) 224;
        }
    }
    char ch = strISO_8859_1.charAt(i);
    if (ch <= 127 ){
        res += ch;
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

That method is based on enconding utf-8 to iso-8859-1 of this website.
[Encoding utf-8 to iso-8859-1](http://string-functions.com/encodingtable.aspx?encoding=65001&decoding=28591)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons IO [Charsets class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/Charsets.html) can come in handy:

```
String utf8String = new String(org.apache.commons.io.Charsets.ISO_8859_1.encode(latinString).array())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to convert UNICODE (ISO_8859_1) to UTF-8

```
public static String String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8(String strISO_8859_1) {
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < strISO_8859_1.length(); i++) {
  final char ch = strISO_8859_1.charAt(i);
  if (ch <= 127) 
  {
      stringBuilder.append(ch);
  }
  else 
  {
      stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", (int)ch));
  }
}
String s = stringBuilder.toString();
int len = s.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                         + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
String strUTF_8 =new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
return strUTF_8;
}
```

**TEST**

```
String strA_ISO_8859_1_i = new String("الغلاف".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

System.out.println("ISO_8859_1 strA est = "+ strA_ISO_8859_1_i + "\n String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8 = " + String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8(strA_ISO_8859_1_i));
```

**RESULT**

> ISO_8859_1 strA est = Ø§ÙØºÙØ§Ù String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8 = الغلاف

Answer (score 1):

Regex can also be good and be used effectively (Replaces all UTF-8 characters not covered in `ISO-8859-1` with space):

```
String input = "€Tes¶ti©ng [§] al€l o€f i¶t _ - À ÆÑ with some 9umbers as"
            + " w2921**#$%!@# well Ü, or ü, is a chaŒracte⚽";
String output = input.replaceAll("[^\\u0020-\\u007e\\u00a0-\\u00ff]", " ");
System.out.println("Input = " + input);
System.out.println("Output = " + output);
```