# Javamail ISO-8859-1 formatting

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, iso-8859-1

I made an E- Mail Client for my Android phone with the Javamail Api. If I try to get the sender's mail address and the recipients mail address with the following methods:

```
Address[] froma = m.getFrom();
        String from = InternetAddress.toString(froma);

        Address[] toa = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
        String to = InternetAddress.toString(toa);
```

I get a String like this back:

"Georg =?ISO-8859-1?Q?SP=E4the?= 
and it has to be Georg Späthe or Georg Spaethe.

I think the Problem is that this are German Mails with another encoding. Can anybody help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MIME headers are encoded as per [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt), therefore you need to decode them first.

```
String decoded = MimeUtility.decodeText("Georg =?ISO-8859-1?Q?SP=E4the?=");
```

JDK import:

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
```

For Android:

```
import com.android.email.mail.internet;
```

See also [Javadoc of MimeUtility](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html)

Answer (score 0):

Each of the Address objects will be an InternetAddress, cast it to that and use the getAddress or getPersonal method depending on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: You can cast to `InternetAddress` and use `toUnicodeString` that will return the decoded mail in the form of `"Georg Späthe" <georg.spaethe@example.com>` if your input address was `"Georg =?ISO-8859-1?Q?SP=E4the?=" <georg.spaethe@example.com>`. ALso, as explained by Bill Shannon, you can call `getPersonal` and `getAddress` to get the decoded values, so there is no need to fiddle around with `MimeUtility` yourself.