# Convert MySql string ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 with Java

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, iso-8859-1

In a MySql database I have a column that contains a `varchar` string encoded with ISO-8859-1 (latin1_swedish_ci).

When the string is not `latin1` MySql stores it, for example, as `"à¸à¸µà¹à¸à¸."`

Using Java I need to extract it and convert it to UTF-8.

Do you know how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to add more detail on where the string comes from and how you are inserting it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652161/how-do-i-convert-between-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like ...

```
byte[] inIso_8859_1 = "à¸à¸µà¹à¸à¸.".getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
byte[] inUtf_8 = new String(inIso_8859_1, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

to check the UTF-8 encoding bytes

```
String s = new String(inUtf_8, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
à¸à¸µà¹à¸à¸.
```

Comment: Thanks!
but doing like that in some cases i have some characters not converted, or actually...they are, but i see ◻
Any ideas?

Comment: You have to ensure that you are displaying the UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: Minor detail: what's "latin1" for MySQL is windows-1252 for the rest of the world.