# Preserve unicode codepoints between ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 conversions in XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Please note this is not the same question as mentioned above since XML escaping to preserve codepoints is possible.

I have a UTF-8 XML file which I can send via HTTP to some other system which I have no control over. For whatever crazy reason it decides to convert it to ISO-8859-1 loosing many Unicode characters and replacing them with '?'. This system then sends someone else this converted XML  document.

How in Java on the sending side can I escape any arbitrary XML with non ASCII codepoints so that they survive this intermediary system and can still be decoded correctly by the endpoint?

A --(UTF-8)--> B --(ISO-8859-1)--> C (Decodes to internal Unicode representation).

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.CharSequenceTranslator;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.translate.NumericEntityEscaper;

public class Test {
    private static CharSequenceTranslator translator = StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML
            .with(NumericEntityEscaper.between(0x7f, Integer.MAX_VALUE));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<note>\n<to>Tove</to>\n<from>Jani</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Don't forget me this weekend!test☠ä</body>\n</note>";
        String xmlEscapedS = xmlToRobustXml(s);
        System.out.println(xmlEscapedS);
    }

    /**
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    public static String xmlToRobustXml(String s) {
        s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Form.NFC);
        String xmlEscapedS = translator.translate(s);
        return xmlEscapedS;
    }
}
```

I tried this but it escapes everything.

```
&lt;note&gt;
&lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;
&lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt;
&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;
&lt;body&gt;Don&apos;t forget me this weekend!test&#9760;&#228;&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/note&gt;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652161/how-do-i-convert-between-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8-in-java)

Comment: @PaulVargas Slightly different in the case of XML since &#xxx; is possible. I am not sure how to do this with any existing XML library however.

Comment: Can't you just send it an ISO-8859-1 encoded document? All the code points outside that range can then be escaped using [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references).

Comment: @McDowell Can you tell me which library does this? I have no experience in this.

Comment: How do you produce your XML file? Do you use `javax.xml.Transformer` or something else?

Comment: @parsifal simple-xml but I don't mind switching to something else or passing it through some other xml parser to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three standard API methods to produce ISO-8859-1 encoded documents.

Using the [StAX API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/package-summary.html):

```
// output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// transcode
StringReader xml = new StringReader("<x>pi: \u03A0</x>");
XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventReader(
    xml);
XMLEventWriter writer = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLEventWriter(
    buffer, "ISO-8859-1");
try {
  writer.add(reader);
} finally {
  writer.close();
}
// proof
String decoded = new String(buffer.toByteArray(),
    Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println(decoded);
```

Using the [DOM API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/package-frame.html):

```
// output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// create XML DOM
InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader("<x>pi: \u03A0</x>"));
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(src);
// serialize
DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
LSOutput out = impl.createLSOutput();
out.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
out.setByteStream(buffer);
impl.createLSSerializer().write(doc, out);
// proof
String decoded = new String(buffer.toByteArray(),
    Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println(decoded);
```

Using the [transform package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-frame.html):

```
// output stream
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// transformation
StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new StringReader("<x>pi: \u03A0</x>"));
StreamResult res = new StreamResult(buffer);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
transformer.transform(src, res);
// proof
String decoded = new String(buffer.toByteArray(),
    Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
System.out.println(decoded);
```

Which you would use depends on your use case; the StAX API is probably the most efficient.

All this sample code will emit documents equivalent to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><x>pi: &#x3a0;</x>
```

Comment: What are the outputs of these different methods for my example input?

Comment: @EricdesCourtis The sample string does not render correctly on my browser - `!test☠ä` - I see a Unicode replacement character followed by a U+00E4 SMALL LETTER A WITH DIARESIS. ä is supported by ISO-8859-1 so there is no guarantee it will be escaped.

Comment: I'll check the answer tomorrow and accept you answer if it ends up working.

Comment: Switching to ASCII encoding turns out to be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode code points above 127 can be encoded as numeric entities like `&#123;` using the following:

From Apache commons [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29). Read the javadoc, by default `escapeXML` does not convert to numeric entities.

```
StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML
    .with(NumericEntityEscaper.between(0x7f, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

BTW you also try sending the original XML using a header `Content-Type: application/x-xml`, so binary transfer.

Comment: Node B receives correctly as UTF-8 but then converts to ISO-8859-1 when writing to disk. Unfortunately I have no control over this part.