# Why getBytes() encoding conversion gives these results

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a String in `UTF-8` which I first convert into `ISO-8859_1` and then convert it back to `UTF-8` and get `ISO8859_1` bytes from it. The result is supposed to be `ISO-8859-1` again, but instead it gives me `UTF-8` bytes. Why?

```
  import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;      

  public class Test  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws
        UnsupportedEncodingException  {
        String s0 = "H\u00ebllo";
        byte[] bytes = s0.getBytes("ISO8859_1");
        byte[] bytes1=s0.getBytes("UTF-8");
        printBytes(bytes, "bytes");  //72 -21 108 108 111  (ISO-8859-1)
        printBytes(bytes1, "bytes1");  //72 -61 -85 108 108 111  (UTF-8)
        byte[] bytes2=new String(s0.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO8859_1").getBytes("ISO8859_1");
        printBytes(bytes2, "bytes2");  //72 -61 -85 108 108 111  (UTF-8)
       }


   private static void printBytes(byte[] array, String name)  {
           System.out.print(name+": ");
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)  {
                    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets instead of the string representation?  (instead of "UTF-8", StandardCharsets.UTF_8, and so on, see the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense:

```
new String(s0.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO8859_1")
```

You are interpreting a `UTF-8` `byte[]` with `ISO8859_1` encoding. You should interpret `UTF-8` bytes with `UTF-8` encoding:

```
new String(s0.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
```

Then it will print:

```
bytes: 72 -21 108 108 111 
bytes1: 72 -61 -85 108 108 111 
bytes2: 72 -21 108 108 111
```

---

You also say:

> I have a String in `UTF-8`

`String`s don't have a well-defined internal encoding, it is an implementation detail. After you create a `String` there is no encoding, you just have a `String`. You can, however, get a `byte[]` from it with a specific encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense now.

Comment: The idea of the String encoding came from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38913688/4759176 - the String in ISO obviously isn't displayed properly, while the String in UTF-8 is fine, so it looks like there are encodings...

Comment: Now that I looked, in that answer the same approach is used - the bytes are taken in encoding `X` and the second argument to the String constructor is an encoding `Y`...

Comment: @parsecer That's the encoding of the `byte[]`. The `String` uses a different encoding internally. Where the `String` contains some characters that can not be represented with ISO encoding, so they don't display properly. The point I'm trying to make is that there is a given level of abstraction. Sure `String`s have an internal encoding, but which one is not made public through it's interface, and shouldn't matter in it's use.

Comment: @parsecer About that answer. All I can say is that it looks wrong to me (and by my best logic _is_ wrong). [The Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.lang.String-) also seems to agree with me saying that that constructor: _"Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified charset."_. Besides, you saw yourself that it didn't work right?

Comment: If the String encoding is not that important, then why using `String new ="Hëllo"` `printBytes(new.getBytes("ISO8859_1")` results in printing out the same `UTF-8` characters, rather than `ISO`'s `-21`? Here the `ë` is the representation of the `\u00eb`.

Comment: Figured that out. Java's storing of the `new` string is at fault, it confuses which encoding this String bytes are initially in. So it's not the method's fault.

Comment: And that's the reason that answer of webmaster works - Java stores `UTF-8` under the `ISO` so when you request `ISO` it really returns you the `UTF-8` representation (in case the initial string is character-gaberish).

Comment: @parsecer You have in your example a `UTF-8` byte array. You then create a `String` from that using the `ISO` encoder. Then you translate it back (with `getBytes`) using the same encoder, which basically does the reverse, so you get a `UTF-8` byte array back. That's also why the other answer works; if you interpret `UTF-8` with `ISO` you see gibberish, but if you then apply the reverse operation to that gibberish, you get `UTF-8` back.

Comment: `new String(s0.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")` yields the same `String` value as `s0`, so going through `getBytes()` is redundant when you can just use `s0` as-is.