# Does Android have an equivalent to string.canBeConvertedToStringEncoding(encoding)

Tags: java, android, objective-c, encoding, character-encoding

In `iOS` there is a method `canBeConvertedToStringEncoding` that will tell you if a given `string` can be encoded to the provided encoding/charset type *(i.e. UTF-8, ISOLatin1 etc...)*. Is there any equivalent built in method available in Android/Java **?**

`iOS` also has a `fastestEncoding` and `smallestEncoding` which will return the best encoding type available for the given string. Does Android have any equivalent for these **?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the android transcode text like this:

```
byte[] utf8 = new String(string, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Please refer to [How do I convert between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652161/how-do-i-convert-between-iso-8859-1-and-utf-8-in-java)

Charset canEncode:

```
boolean ISO = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newEncoder()
                .canEncode(str);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#canEncode()

Comment: Thanks @lazy, but I'm not looking for _how to encode_. Rather if Android has a method for testing __IF__ a string can be converted to a particular encoding _(like iOS does)_. Otherwise you have to try to encode and catch any error, then try another encoding etc...

Comment: @Mudlabs ok,I understand what you want. you can use "Charset"

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have such kind of method, but you can check whether a string can be represented properly in a specific character encoding, by trying encoding/decoding.

For example, you can make your own `string.canBeConvertedToStringEncoding` equivalent as follows:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (canBeConvertedToStringEncoding("abc", "ISO-8859-1")) {
      System.out.println("can be converted");
    } else {
      System.out.println("cannot be converted");
    }

    if (canBeConvertedToStringEncoding("あいう", "ISO-8859-1")) {
      System.out.println("can be converted");
    } else {
      System.out.println("cannot be converted");
    }
  }

  public static boolean canBeConvertedToStringEncoding(String target, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String to = new String(target.getBytes(encoding), encoding);
    return target.equals(to);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");`