# How to parse a string that is in a different encoding from java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a string that I have read in from a Word document. I think it is in "Cp1252" encoding. Java uses UTF8.

How do I search that string for those special characters in Cp1252 and replace them with an appropriate UTF8 character?

specifically, I want to replace the "En Dash"  character with a plain "-"

The following code block takes the projDateString which is coming from the Word document, and trying to do such a thing

```
    char[] test = projDateString.getBytes("Cp1252");
    for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
    System.out.println "test["+ i + "] = " + Integer.toHexString((byte)test[i]);
    }
    String projDateString2 = new String(test);
    projDateString2.replaceAll("\0x96", "\u2013");
    System.out.println("projDateString2: " + projDateString)
```

I am not sure I am setting up projDateString2 correctly. As you can see, the hex value of that dash is ffffff96 when I getBytes on the string using Cp1252 encoding. If I getBytes with UTF8 it comes in as 3 hex values instead of one.

This gives me the following output:

```
test[0] = 30
test[1] = 38
test[2] = 2f
test[3] = 32
test[4] = 30
test[5] = 31
test[6] = 30
test[7] = 20
test[8] = ffffff96
test[9] = 20
test[10] = 50
test[11] = 72
test[12] = 65
test[13] = 73
test[14] = 65
test[15] = 6e
test[16] = 74
projDateString2: 08/2010 ΓÇô Present
```

As you can see, the replace did nothing, and the println still gives me garbage chars instead of a plaintext "-"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java strings are *always* in UTF-16, at least as far as the API is concerned... but you can generally just think of them as being "Unicode". The fact that they're UTF-16 is only really relevant when it comes to characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, i.e. with Unicode values above U+FFFF. They have to be represented as *surrogate pairs* in Java. But I don't think you need to worry about this in your case. So just think of the values in Strings as "Unicode text" without a specific encoding... in particular, definitely *not* in UTF-8 or CP1252. Those are the encodings used to convert *binary* data (e.g. a byte array) into text data (e.g. a string).

You shouldn't be using `String.getBytes()` or `new String(byte[])` without specifying the encoding - *that's* the problem. Those always use the platform default encoding - which is almost *always* the wrong choice.

You say you "have a string that I have read in from a Word document" - how did you read it in? How did it start off life?

If you have the *bytes* and you know the relevant encoding, you should use:

```
String text = new String(bytes, encoding);
```

You should never have to deal with a string which has been created using the wrong encoding - if you get to that stage, you're almost *bound* to be risking information loss. Tackle the problem as early as you possibly can, rather than trying to fix the data up later on.

The *next* thing to understand is that the `String` class in Java is immutable. Calling `replaceAll` on a string *won't change the existing string*. It will instead return a *new* string with the replacements made.

So this statement:

```
projDateString2.replaceAll("\0x96", "\u2013");
```

will *never* do what you want. Even if everything else is correct, you should be using:

```
projDateString2 = projDateString2.replaceAll("\0x96", "\u2013");
```

(or something similar). I don't think that actually *will* do what you want anyway, but you need to be aware of it for when everything else is sorted out.

Comment: I will re-think this comment since you edited while I was writing it.

Comment: not specifying encoding for the mentioned methods simply means they use the default platform encoding. Which is UTF-8, if `-Dfile.encoding` isn't specified.

Comment: @Bozho: It's UTF-8 on *some* platforms, but not on all. Relying on it is basically a bad move. I'll edit this in.

Comment: that you should not rely on the default is completely true

Comment: I am using docx4j to open the word document. It seems to be using a FileInputStream and the load method can be seen here: http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage.java

Comment: Being as I can't really control the input source..and only have access to the String object, what is the best route to go for me to detect the "En Dash" character that I am seeking to replace with a regular unicode "-" dash character

Comment: @Derek: It may well have it correctly to start with. First find out the character it's actually using in Unicode form, then just replace it with `text = text.replaceAll("\uxxxx", "-")` where `\uxxxx` is the appropriate Unicode character. But you should find this out just using *characters*, not doing anything with bytes.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the case here. When I do projDateString.getBytes() and print the (int) cast of the character array, I get three characters that are 65506 65408 and 65427 - which shouldnt be that large right? In thise case what will I need to put in my regex part for the replaceAll()?

Comment: @Derek: *Don't use getBytes()*. Just use `charAt()` and cast each char to an int. That's the way to get the Unicode values. If you use `getBytes()` you're going back into encoding it in binary, which is going to make it harder to work out what's going on. Just don't do it.

Comment: Ah - I see. Thanks. So I think that worked, because I got back a unicode value of 8211 for the character in question, and a 32 on either side of it indicating the spaces. However, my replaceAll("\u8211", "-") still did not work. I am playing with that now..do I need to use a hex value instead perhaps?

Comment: Got it! I had to do my regex using the hex value of the character, which is 2013! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Derek: I would actually use `replace` rather than `replaceAll` - there's no need for a regex here or even strings, as you just want to replace one character with another.

Answer (score 3):

Conversion is generally done by something like this:

```
String properlyEncoded = 
    new String(original.getBytes(originalEncoding), newEncoding);
```

Note that it is not unlikely that some information is lost during the conversion.

Comment: Ok, so I did String projDateString2 = new String(projDateString.getBytes("Cp1252"), "UTF-16"); and I still cannot get the replaceAll to work correctly

Comment: That conversion can very easily be lossy though, because the original incorrect conversion can easily lose information.

Comment: @Jon Skeet true. But you can't prevent the loss, I think.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that you properly convert from CP1252 bytes to Java's [character representation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) (which is UTF-16). Since you're using a library for parsing *.docx* files, this has probably happened.

Now all you need to do is call `projDateString.replace('\u2013', '-')` and do something with the return value. No need for `replaceAll()`, since you're not working with regular expressions.

Comment: I am using docx4j to open the word document. It seems to be using a FileInputStream and the load method can be seen here: http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage.java

Comment: Thanks for the tip abotu the return value - i had that typed up correctly in code..just didnt make it into my SO question

Comment: Updated my answer, you're trying to go from "En Dash" to "-", correct? Otherwise you would have to swap the replace() parameters.