# Java: convert UTF8 String to byte array in another encoding

Tags: java, encoding, cp1251

I have UTF8 encoded String, but I need to post parameters to Runtime process in cp1251. How can I decode String or byte array?

I need smth like:.`bytesInCp1251 = encodeTo(stringInUtf8, "cp1251");`

---

Thanks to all! This is my own solution:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "cp1251");
writer.write(s);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a string that is in a different encoding from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016671/how-to-parse-a-string-that-is-in-a-different-encoding-from-java)

Comment: There are no answer for my question there. I need to _change_ encoding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is no such thing as an "UTF8 encoded String"** in Java. Java Strings use UTF-16 internally, but should be seen as an abstraction without a specific encoding. If you have a String, it's already decoded. If you want to encode it, use `string.getBytes(encoding)`. If you original data is UTF-8, you have to take that into account when you convert that data from bytes to String.

Answer (score 5):

```
byte[] bytesInCp1251 = stringInUtf8.getBytes("cp1251");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is solution!

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "cp1251");
writer.write(s);
```

Comment: You should update your own answer with the solution instead of it being hidden here.