# How to replace characters using Regex

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I received string from IBM Mainframe like below (2bytes graphic fonts)

"　;Ａ;Ｂ;Ｃ;Ｄ;Ｅ;Ｆ;Ｇ;Ｈ;Ｉ;Ｊ;Ｋ;Ｌ;Ｍ;Ｎ;Ｏ;Ｐ;Ｑ;Ｒ;Ｓ;Ｔ;Ｕ;Ｖ;Ｗ;Ｘ;Ｙ;Ｚ;ａ;ｂ;ｃ;ｄ;ｅ;ｆ;ｇ;ｈ;ｉ;ｊ;ｋ;ｌ;ｍ;ｎ;ｏ;ｐ;ｑ;ｒ;ｓ;ｔ;ｕ;ｖ;ｗ;ｘ;ｙ;ｚ;０;１;２;３;４;５;６;７;８;９;｀;－;＝;￦;～;！;＠;＃;＄;％;＾;＆;＊;（;）;＿;＋;｜;［;］;｛;｝;：;＂;＇;，;．;／;＜;＞;？;";

and, I wanna change these characters to 1 byte ascii codes

How can I replace these using java.util.regex.Matcher, String.replaceAll() in Java

target characters :

;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S;T;U;V;W;X;Y;Z;a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;x;y;z;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;`;-;=;\;~;!;@;#;$;%;^;&;*;(;);_;+;|;[;];{;};:;";';,;.;/;<;>;?;";

Comment: regexes shouldn't be used for character encoding translation. See [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that other question.  The OP is talking about actual characters, mostly from the [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms/index.htm), that need to be replaced with ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

This is not (as other responders are saying) a character-encoding issue, but regexes are still the wrong tool.  If Java had an equivalent of Perl's `tr///` operator, *that* would be the right tool, but you can hand-code it easily enough:

```
public static String convert(String oldString)
{
  String oldChars = "　ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ０１２３４５６７８９｀－＝￦～！＠＃＄％＾＆＊（）＿＋｜［］｛｝：＂＇，．／＜＞？";
  String newChars = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`-=\\~!@#$%^&*()_+|[]{}:\"',./<>?";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int len = oldString.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    char ch = oldString.charAt(i);
    int pos = oldChars.indexOf(ch);
    sb.append(pos < 0 ? ch : newChars.charAt(pos));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

I'm assuming each character in the first string corresponds to the character at the same position in the second string, and that the first character (`U+3000`, 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE') should be converted to an ASCII space (`U+0020`).

Be sure to save the source file as UTF-8, and include the `-encoding UTF-8` option when you compile it (or tell your IDE to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this one's about regex, it's about encoding. Should be possible to read into a String with 2-byte and then write it with any other encoding. 
Look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html) for supported encodings.

Comment: It's hard to test/tell from here without having the original byte stream