# How to convert cp1251 to utf-8 programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, cp1251

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encoding conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Actually I need an example, method to convert from cp1251 encoding to utf-8 in Java.
For example, I don't have a headache in PHP with this question because of:

```
iconv($str, "cp1251", "utf-8");
```

So, may be someone had an experience to make these kind of things in Java, please help.
Thx in advance.

Comment: I hate the communities like kamaci, Wooble, TryTryAgain, Mark, alfasin - this kills all social sites like SO. The most useful answer is the method (program) that solves it, and why some people could just delete my adequate comments?! I don't want it, nobody does. And pals -3 for what, for "dublicate"? Are U insane? Oh sorry, I'd forgot that Your points achieved by nothing at all.

Answer (score 6):

As opposed to PHP, strings in Java have no inherent byte-level encoding. They are native UTF-16 strings. So if you want a file re-encoded, just read it with one encoding and write with the other. Check out `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`.

Comment: It is not actually InputStreamReder it is InputStreamReader

Comment: Indeed you are right. Did that cause any confusion for you?

Comment: In sense of crawling through Java API no, thanks.