# How to convert UTF8 string to UTF16

Tags: java, utf-8, utf-16

I'm getting a UTF8 string by processing a request sent by a client application. But the string is really UTF16. What can I do to get it into my local string is a letter followed by `\0` character? I need to convert that String into UTF16.

Sample received string:  `S\0a\0m\0p\0l\0e` (UTF8).
What I want is : `Sample` (UTF16)

```
FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
String field = "";
String value = "";
if (item.isFormField()) {
  try{
    value=item.getString();
    System.out.println("====" + value);
  }
```

Comment: A String is a sequence of characters. The encoding matters only when you transform a String to bytes and vice-versa (when writing or reading to/from a file for example). Show us some code, because what you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: No requirement of doing UTF-16 or UTF-8 conversion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bytes from the server are *not* UTF-8 if they look like `S\0a\0m\0p\0l\0e`. They are UTF-16. You can convert UTF16 bytes to a Java `String` with:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
String string = new String(bytes, "UTF-16");
```

Or you can use `UTF-16LE` or `UTF-16BE` as the character set name if you know the endian-ness of the byte stream coming from the server.

If you've already (mistakenly) constructed a `String` from the bytes as if it were UTF-8, you can convert to UTF-16 with:

```
string = new String(string.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-16");
```

However, as JB Nizet points out, this round trip (bytes -> UTF-8 string -> bytes) is potentially lossy if the bytes weren't valid UTF-8 to start with.

Comment: I would say that if he has already constructed a String from the bytes as if it were UTF-8, then there is a bug, and this shouldn't have been done. Every sequence of bytes is not valid UTF-8, and trying to transform random bytes (or UTF-16 bytes) into an UTF8 String is a potentially lossy process.

Answer (score -2):

## I propose the following solution:

> NSString *line_utf16[ENOUGH_MEMORY_SIZE];
>
> line_utf16= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", line_utf8];
>
> ENOUGH_MEMORY_SIZE is at least twice exceeds memory used for line_utf8

I suppose memory for
**line_utf16**
has to be dynamically or statically allocated at least twice of the size of
**line_utf8**.

*If you run into similar problem please add a couple of sentences!*

Comment: The question was about how to do the conversion in Java.