# Charset.defaultCharset() Result Differs when Running from Eclipse or JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, character-encoding, default

I have a very simple code:

```
package org;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
  }
}
```

I run it on Windows7 RUS JRE7.

When I run it from Eclipse 4.2 (20120614-1722) with "Debug" or "Run" (I didn't set any additional encoding preferences for Eclipse or project), I get the following result:

```
windows-1252
```

And it seems correct for me.

But when I pack this with ANT 1.8.2 into JAR with default settings:

```
<project name="Test" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Simple build XML
    </description>
    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

    <target name="init">
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source" >
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution" >
        <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>
        <!-- Put everything from ${build} into the test.jar file -->
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/test.jar" basedir="${build}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.Test"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

I get the following result when running it:

```
>java -jar test.jar
windows-1251
```

I was hoping to get the same result here. What am I doing wrong? Which is the correct way to determine default charset then?

Update:
The reason to ask this question was, that I don't really read or write file, where I can specify encoding manually. I simply have a String returned from 
    **javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info.getName()** 
and need to display it properly in different system charsets.

Update2:
It seems, that the reason is that javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info.getName() encodes the "System Charset" specific result with CP1251, so I need to decode it back to "System Charset". But how to find it out?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you should never rely on default character encoding:

[How to Find the Default Charset/Encoding in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-default-charset-encoding-in-java)

[Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Instead, when you write or read you need to specify desired encoding explicitly.

For example, 2nd constructor should be preferred.

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in) 
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't read or write - there, yes, I can specify the encoding manually. I get a String from javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.getName() and need to display it properly with system encoding.

Comment: @RyabikovAleksey, to display where? Console, GUI? What encoding `getName` is supposed to produce?

Comment: I have a GUI application, if it plays role. I suppose it produses CP1251. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.Info.html#getName()

Comment: I used this code to convert: result=new String(result.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()), "CP1251"); but it fails in JAR, but works fine in debug.

Comment: @RyabikovAleksey, in which GUI component you want to show? Use `UTF-8`

Comment: I display it in swing JComboBox, but setting UTF-8 gives incorrect result.

Comment: I think that the reason is that javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info.getName() encodes the OS Charset specific result with CP1251, so I need to decode it back to "OS Charset"

Comment: @RyabikovAleksey, I believe it should not. Have you tried not converting at all? Just get and show? In Eclipse try to see implementation.

Comment: Not converting does not work either, otherwise there would be no question :-) Looking in implementation gives that Info.name is only set in constructor, but constructor call search gives nothing...