# Converting String of 0 and 1 to another string

Tags: java

I have a string of 0 and 1. I want to convert this string into another string by taking the 8 characters at a time and converting it to an Integer in binary and then casting this Integer to a character.

Code :

```
String s2="";
String s="10000111";
char nextChar;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 8) 
{
     nextChar = (char)Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+8), 2);
     System.out.println(nextChar);
     s2 += nextChar;
}
```

The code gives the right answer if I run it as a simple java file, but when I run it in a web application, it gives strange results. Why is this, and how can I get the web application to produce the same result?

In desktop application :

http://postimg.org/image/ww88p3ot5/

In web application :

(in browser)

```
135, 
31, 
120,x 
27, 
192,À 
242,ò 
146, 
128, 
255,ÿ 
14, 
11, 
107,k 
159,
```

(on output screen)

http://postimg.org/image/ydn9h9nsf/

Comment: Is this line `String s=10000111;` compile?

Comment: @Masud Sorry, just a typo error.

Comment: what are these "strange results"?

Comment: When the web app gives an output that's different from that of a desktop app, check your encoding.

Comment: In my console your code print the unicode of 135.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How to check it ? also i want it to be same as that of my present desktop one.As my further computations depend largely on that

Comment: What kind of web app? GWT?

Comment: @Masud I want the same in my web app to.Please help

Comment: @user3509463 java tipically use UTF-8 charset, while web tipically uses (old) ISO-8859-1. You can enforce the use of UTF-8 charset (you have to modify header, so tipically is a web-server config)

Comment: @staticx No, a simple one using jsp and servlet in java

Comment: @lesto How to change it ? Please help

Comment: @lesto: Java's native encoding is UTF16BE. That doesn't mean it always uses UTF16. The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying operating system.

Comment: @user3509463: See this answer. Implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/229022/2591612