# Java - Convert String from String to IBM437 Character Code

Tags: java

What I'm trying to accomplish is converting a character such as ☺ to an IBM437 character code. That is, ☺, would turn into a one, ☻ would turn into a two and so fourth (all according to the location of the specified character in the font: [image from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#mediaviewer/File:Codepage-437.png).)

I've tried several different methods and done some heavy researching on the internet. After all, as pretty usual, it ends in asking a question on good old *stackoverflow*.

Thanks y'all,
Foru

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encoding conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229015/encoding-conversion-in-java)

Comment: It's fairly possible. I, however, can't seem to figure out how to use it properly. :-(

Comment: `"☺".getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("IBM-437"))`

Comment: That for me returns the number 64 once having converted the byte to an integer. That is, simply casting it. That is the same with attempting to convert ☻ to IBM437. That also, as a matter of fact, converts to the number 63.

Answer (score 0):

Arent you just able to use, [Charset](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) To convert the encoding, if that is the question your answering, and Im sure their are some library's you can use.