# Bash: Strange characters even after setting locale to UTF-8: "•" prints as "ΓÇó"

Tags: bash, character-encoding, mingw, git-bash

We have some Groovy scripts that we run from Git Bash (MINGW64) in Windows.
Some scripts prints the bullet character • (or similar).
To make it work we set this variable:

`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

But, for some people, this is not enough. Its console prints `ΓÇó` instead of `•`.

Any idea about how to make it prints properly and why is printing that even after setting the LC_ALL variable?

**Update**

The key part is that the output from Groovy scripts is printing incorrectly, but there are no problems with the plain bash scripts.

Comment: It could have something to do with their console or terminal character encoding settings.

Comment: `LC_ALL` affects your shell and (since it's exported) the programs running under it. I doesn't affect your terminal program, and it looks like your terminal is using [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or something similar.

Comment: If the `en_US.UTF-8` locale is not installed on the system, `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` will fail but this failure is not detectable by testing the return code. Use `locale -a` to query system available locales first.

Comment: Which $TERM? Could you write down the codepoints of •? Some terminals doesn't handle combining characters, and/or non BMP (so characters above 0xFFFF): they say they are just UCS level 1. -- On my computer:` LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 echo "• $MSYSTEM $MINGW_CHOST"` gives me `• MINGW64 x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Could you give us an example?

Comment: I added an update: with plain bash scripts the bullet is printed fine. The problems comes with groovy script output.
`• MINGW64 x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Comment: @Agorreca You could possibly piipe the groovy (gradle?) output to `| iconv -f 'UTF-8' -t "$(locale charmap)//TRANSLIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example with querying the current characters mapping `locale charmap` used by the system locale, and filtering the output with recode to render it with compatible characters mapping:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cat <<EOF | recode -qf "UTF-8...$(locale charmap)"
• These are
• UTF-8 bullets in source
• But it can gracefully degrade with recode
EOF
```

With a `charmap=ISO-8859-1` it renders as:

```
o These are
o UTF-8 bullets in source
o But it can gracefully degrade with recode
```

Alternate method using `iconv` instead of `recode` and results may even be better.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cat <<EOF | iconv -f 'UTF-8' -t "$(locale charmap)//TRANSLIT"
• These are
• UTF-8 bullets followed by a non-breaking space in source
• But it can gracefully degrade with iconv
• Europe's currency sign is € for Euro.
EOF
```

`iconv` output with an `fr_FR.iso-8859-15@Euro` locale:

```
o These are
o UTF-8 bullets followed by a non-breaking space in source
o But it can gracefully degrade with iconv
o Europe's currency sign is € for Euro.
```

Comment: Great! Sorry for the delay, it happens on other users (not me) so I needed to be tested in other machines. Yes, you nailed it! Thanks. Do you know a way to set it as default conversion (or something like that?). We are using a lot of scripts and maybe add the iconv pipe in each, I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @Agorreca if you encounter the problem only with Groovy, maybe you could use Java standard libraries to convert the characters mapping to that of system. See: [Encoding conversion in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229023/7939871)