# Save cyrillic while change String encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1251 in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1251

I try to swap encoding from UTF-8 to windows-1251, but all my solutions works only with latin letters.
So I want to change encoding in cyrillic String. How can I do it correctly?

All solutions with creating a new String from bytes don't save [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) letters.

For ex:
UTF-8 - Some текст с кириллицей and latin
windows-1251 - Some С‚РµРєСЃС‚ СЃ РєРёСЂРёР»Р»РёС†РµР№ and latin

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Is this all the code? I can't see anything related UTF-8.

Comment: And please add the code to the question and not as a comment.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Codo I must assume that the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293780/save-cyrillic-while-change-string-encoding-from-utf-8-to-windows-1251-in-java#comment132861745_75293780) above was as reply to my comment (despite missing the `@user` annotation) I am not the author of the question, I posted a suggestion for the OP (I did not use `@Codo` in my first comment, should be implicit that it is addressed to OP [even if the site notified you]) And sure it is not all code, but the *heart* of how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

## Specify character encoding for writing

You can specify a character encoding with the [`CharSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class.

The [NIO.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) framework in modern Java makes easy work of writing text to a file. For example, [`Files.writeString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).

This code works for me:

```java
String original = "Some текст с кириллицей";
byte[] win1251Bytes = new byte[ 0 ];
try { win1251Bytes = original.getBytes( "windows-1251" ); } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
Path path = Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus.txt" );  // Home folder on macOS.
try { Files.write( path , win1251Bytes ); } catch ( IOException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
```

Or, this briefer code works too, per the [Comment by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75293780/save-cyrillic-while-change-string-encoding-from-utf-8-to-windows-1251-in-java/75294350?noredirect=1#comment132893349_75294350) below.

```java
try
{
    Files.writeString(
            Paths.get( "/Users/whatever/bogus.txt" ) ,
            "Some текст с кириллицей" ,
            Charset.forName( "windows-1251" ) 
    );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}
```

I know nothing about Cyrillic text. I just read the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html) first. Then I read [*Writing byte[] to a File in Java*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-byte-array-file) page at Baeldung.com. And in the Javadoc for [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), I found a mention that if a character set is supported in Java, we should be able to use its name as listed in [IANA Charset Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets). By following that link, I found the name `"windows-1251"`.

Run that code to create the file.

## Specify character encoding for reading

Open the file in a [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) of your choice. Be sure to tell the app to  **interpret the [octets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) in the file as Windows-1251** encoding.

Here I chose to use the [*TextEdit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) app by Apple, bundled with [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/macOS). In the File > Open dialog box for TextEdit, notice the `Options` button used to display a list of character encodings. Choose *Cyrillic (Windows)* there, as that seems to mean [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251).

[image: screenshot of TextEdit.app File > Open > Options dialog box]

If the text is properly interpreted, we see the original Cyrillic characters.

[image]

## Defaults

Be aware that until Java 17 and earlier, for most purposes the Java runtime **defaults to the character encoding native to the host OS**. This default applies to writing and reading text files, among other things.

As of Java 18 and later, the Java runtime **defaults to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** character encoding for most purposes. This default applies across all host platforms (macOS, Linux, Windows, etc.). See [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400).

So when you need an alternate character encoding such as *Windows 1251*, **always specify the `CharSet`** explicitly.

Comment: You can use the method for writing a string in the first place, `Files.writeString(path, original, Charset.forName("windows-1251"));` (since JDK 11) or `Files.write(path, Collections.singleton(original), Charset.forName("windows-1251"));` (since JDK 7)